# End-of-degree project geolocalize real time a dron

Tags: html, json, angular, database, integration

1º of all sorry for my english. I'm performing my end degree project which consists in geolocalizing a drone and show the parameters in a web. I have done the part by which drone sends the parameters and a server (my raspberry) receives these data (I'm working with java thanks to the teachers XD).

Now I should integrate these parameters to the web (I'm doing this with Angular 9). My doubt comes here: Should I inject parameters into a DB and then the web takes the data? Or should I send the data via JSON?

I'm a little stuck here, any advise?

Comment: The data have to be show in real time ?

Comment: Sure, i must show a marker of a dron in a google map

Comment: So you will definitively have to use a Websocket server and in this case it's not necessary to use a database.